# sort numerical characters within a string in r

Tags: r, string, sorting

I am trying to sort numbers inside a string:

```
library(gtools)
gtools::mixedsort("[20,12,30]", decreasing = FALSE)
```

Which returns the same string:

```
"[20,12,30]"
```

Expected output:

```
"[12,20,30]"
```

Am I missing any argument inside `mixedsort()`?

Is there any other way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may extract the elements, sort and paste

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_chr(str_extract_all("[20,12,30]", "\\d+"),
       ~ sprintf('[%s]', toString(sort(as.numeric(.x)))))
```

-output

```
[1] "[12, 20, 30]"
```

---

Or in `base R`, another option is to replace the `[/]` with `(/)`, append the `c`, `eval/parse` to return the numeric vector, `sort` and then reconstruct the original format with `sprint/toString`

```
sprintf('[%s]', toString(sort(eval(parse(text =
       paste0("c", chartr("[]", "()", "[20,12,30]")))))))
[1] "[12, 20, 30]"
```

---

Another option would be to make use of `reticulate` as the format string is a `list` structure in `python`

```
library(reticulate)
py_run_string(paste0("a=", "[20,12,30]"))
sprintf('[%s]', toString(sort(py$a)))
[1] "[12, 20, 30]"
```

---

`mixedsort/mixedorder` sorts not within a string, but across strings